# Finding thickness in a boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have

$$ \varepsilon y'' + (1+x)^2 y' + y = 0 , x \in [0,1], y(0)=y(1)=1$$

I know since $(1+x)^2 > 0$ that boundary layer will be near $x = 0$. We have to find inner solution $y_{inner}$ and to do this we introduce $x = \delta X$ and so we have

$$ \underbrace{ \frac{ \varepsilon }{\delta^2} Y'' }_{(I)}+ \underbrace{\frac{(1+x)^2}{\delta} Y' }_{(II)} + \underbrace{ Y }_{(III)} = 0  $$

$\delta( \epsilon )$ is the thickness of the boundary layer.

since the $x \sim 0 $, then term in $(II)$ is $\sim \frac{1}{\delta}$. The term in (III) is of order $1$. so this equation will be balanced when the order of (I) is 1 so $ \delta^2 = \varepsilon $ so $\boxed{\delta =  \sqrt{ \epsilon } }$. Is this correct?

Im still unsure. Im having difficulties trying to understand how to balance the equation in order to obtain the thickness. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the second term does not remain bounded in this balancing. You have to multiply with $δ$ to get 
$$
\underbrace{ \frac{ε}{δ} Y'' }_{(I)}+ \underbrace{(1+x)^2 Y' }_{(II)} + \underbrace{δ Y }_{(III)} = 0
$$
to get the first two terms balanced with $δ=ε^1$ while the third becomes infinitesimal.